# How to keep original image dimensions for images in Microsoft Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word, import, image-editing

When I'm importing images into a Word document, if the image is a small image like 100x100px, then the image is imported as something like 300x300, thus making it hideously blurry.

This necessitates myself resizing the image so that it looks not as blurry, but it does not look the same at all.

It also seems that it happens with `png` files but not `bmp` files.

Is there a way to import the image at its original size?

Comment: What's the source of your images?

Comment: I'm using Word 2007 on Win 7. All images can be inserted with their original size. What version of MS Windows and Office are you using?

Comment: Andy: screenshots.

Comment: Mepher: Windows 7 64 bit and Office 2007.

Comment: @Nitrodist: how can a screenshot be 300x300?

Comment: ......Cropping?

Comment: @Andy also alt+printscreen!

Comment: if you use some software to do the cropping that will prolly be the easiest place to change the physical size/DPI...

Comment: didn't know about alt+printscreen... it lets you choose a part of the screen?

Comment: It gets the screen from the active window.

Comment: I'm getting a similar issue with large screenshots being reduced in size.  Win 2K8R2, Word 2010.

Answer (score 11):

1. Open the image in a browser, preferably Firefox or Chrome, and copy the image.
2. Turn view of the document to "web layout".
3. Paste the image in -- it should appear in full resolution.
4. You can now change back to your standard view and try to handle formatting from there.

This is the ONLY way I've been able to get it to work half-way right (especially using large resolution images), finally I'm getting the full resolution though.  Of course your pages may not be able to display the full-size image depending on the actual resolution, so if you want them visible saving them in a format such at html may be preferable.

In Word 2010 it makes no difference if you use print view or web layout view, the above will work in either.

If you do have software to adjust the ppi of the image: Word uses 96 ppi so any 96ppi image scaled at 100% in Word will look at its sharpest.

Answer (score 6):

For years I've struggled with the same problem: Screenshots inserted via Cut&Paste (or Word's own function "Insert screenshot") sometimes get blurred, sometimes not.

But it seems I've found a stunningly simple solution now (Windows 7, Word 2013):

1. Switch your document to Print Layout (View->Print Layout).
2. Set the zoom level to 100% (View->100%).
3. Paste your image from clipboard or use Word's Insert->Screenshot function.

The key is to zoom to 100% - with any other zoomlevel, the inserted screenshot image gets blurred.

**Note:** This works for me even if I adjust the Windows 7 display scaling to more than 100% (96 dpi) (via Control Panel->Display).

Answer (score 4):

After having copied the image, use MS Word's `Paste Special` option. Select `Paste as Device Independent Bitmap` option. That should do the trick.

Comment: Can you be more explicit in your instructions? I can't quite follow them.

Comment: Basically you don't have to insert the picture but COPY it from somewhere else like a browser, a editing software. Just copy there the image and paste it in Word (tested with Word 2010, Chome abd Gimp) =)

Answer (score 1):

In Word 2010, I found that just right-clicking the (scaled-down) picture, selecting Size and Position and then clicking the Reset button restores the image in its full glory.

Comment: For me, this doesn't work. Word "resets" it's own values and even if the size is set to 100% for Word, the image is still bigger than the original...

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be solved with setting the DPI value of your images, because MS Word is using DPI to set what amount of space an image needs.
For example with irfanview you can change the DPI of any image to tell how much space you need.
I had to fit 1000 low res pictures into Word and I wanted to avoid resizing one by one.
With irfanview batch conversion I set each image to 250 DPI and it is about 12 images per page.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Word 2007 but I think I might know what's going on here. A picture has two important relevant attributes: the resolution (ie dimension in pixels) and the DPI (number of dots to be printed per inch). You can have a 25x25 pixel image with a DPI of 10, that will be 2.5" square, and horrendously blurry. If your picture comes from a scanner then it's likely to have the correct size already. Otherwise the software tends to insert a standard 'default' DPI, that might be inappropriate. A decent image editing program lets you change the DPI. In fact you *might* be able to do it in properties from the Windows shell, but I'm not on Win any more, so I can't check.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled for this for years.  Any image will be scaled and blurred when pasted into Word, even when setting the image to appear at 100%.  I just fixed this for possibly the first time ever, using Word 2010, by doing this:

1. Open the image in Adobe Photoshop CS5.5.
2. Choose File -> Save for Web and Devices...
3. Choose "PNG-24" from the "Preset" popup menu at the top right and click Save
4. From Word 2010, click the Insert tab and then "Picture" and then choose the picture.

Miraculously, the image appears unscaled, as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Save full image size, open file in MSpaint. Select All, copy, paste into MSWord.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

- Paste the correctly sized picture into MSPaint.
- Save it as the name you want to use (I always use the .png type).
- Now zoom in the negative direction until you see all of the exposed white border area of the MSPaint window.
- Click on it, you should see aspect blocks on the four corners and in the middle between the corners.
- Grab the lower right corner with your mouse and slide it up until it is the size of your picture.
- Click save again.
- This time when you insert the picture into Word it will not include that large white area that was around the outside of the paint picture previously.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem with bringing screenshots into Word 2016.

The problem is that Word wants to bring your 96 dpi image into a 220 dpi document. (Your dpi values may vary.)

When, say, a screenshot is pasted into Word, it inflates the size by a factor of 220 dpi/96 dpi ≈ 2.29167. (I don't understand the point of this "feature", but this is what my Word install does by default.)

To counteract this, after having pasted the image in, right click on the image and click 'Size and Position...". In the Scale subpanel, set your height and width percentages to 96/220 ≈ 43.6436%. This will scale the image back down to its original dpi.

**Bonus pro tip:** 
Wait until you've got all your (poorly sized) images pasted into your document; don't resize any of them until you're done writing the doc. When ready, resize the first image as described above and hit Okay. Then click the next image once and hit F4. F4 repeats the last process, so hitting F4 will now resize the next image to ~43.6%. Click the next image and repeat your way down the file.

**PS:** Incidentally, changes to *File>Options>Advanced>Image Size and Quality>Set default target output to...* do *not* affect how my install of Word resizes pasted-in images.

Answer (score -1):

None of these worked for me....  It seems to be dependent on the document formatting.  For me, I went into Word options (under file).
Advanced :  The insert / paste picture as : in front of text.

this prevents it reformating to fit with your text, you can then muck about it with afterwards!  Works fine now.

Comment: Your instructions are not very clear.

Answer (score -1):

I tried everything but nothing worked.  I wanted to paste a screenshot from a phone (1080 X 1920) to a Word 2013 doc, and have the picture in the word doc be the same size as the phone.  Here's what worked for me:

- Just drag the picture into the document
- Right click on the picture and choose Format Picture
- Size tab
- Uncheck Relative to Original Picture size (height and width go to 100%)
- Change the percentage to what you want (56% in this case)
- OK

Answer (score -1):

If you are using MS office 2010,

1. From the toolbar select the button insert.
2. Now select picture from the task bar of insert.
3. Now select the image from the pop up window.
4. Then on the lower right-hand size clock on the lower arrow besides the insert button.
5. Now select link to file.

Comment: The OP has specifically asked for answers for Office 2007.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you have not zoomed in the document to say 120%. This was the mistake for me, turned it back to 100%, I dragged and dropped the image, and it's all proper size now.
So all in all, drag and drop works as it should, no resizing.

Comment: When you import images to word it is set to fit width of page. Document zoom changes how you see it, but it has nothing to do with picture resizing.

Comment: Mine is not set to fit